# how to initialize a buffer

Tags: c, sockets, buffer

This is my server/client sockets code.
I have a problem with the buffer, when the client receives the message from the server which is the buffer (i initialized it to "12") the output shows like this:

```
[+]Client Socket is created.
[+]Connected to Server.
Temp : 
  12121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212 
  12121212121212�L��Q�
```

server :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 4444

int main(){

int sockfd, ret;
 struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;

int clientSocket;
struct sockaddr_in newAddr;

socklen_t addr_size;

char buffer[1024];
    char Temp[4]= "12";
pid_t childpid;

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(sockfd < 0){
    printf("[-]Error in connection.\n");
    exit(1);
}
printf("[+]Server Socket is created.\n");

memset(&serverAddr, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr));
serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

ret = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
if(ret < 0){
    printf("[-]Error in binding.\n");
    exit(1);
}
printf("[+]Bind to port %d\n", 4444);

if(listen(sockfd, 10) == 0){
    printf("[+]Listening....\n");
}else{
    printf("[-]Error in binding.\n");
}


while(1){
    clientSocket = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&newAddr, &addr_size);
    if(clientSocket < 0){
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Connection accepted from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(newAddr.sin_addr), 
   ntohs(newAddr.sin_port));

    if((childpid = fork()) == 0){
        close(sockfd);

        while(1){



        send(clientSocket, Temp, strlen(Temp), 0);
                bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            if(strcmp(Temp, ":exit") == 0){
                printf("Disconnected from %s:%d\n", 
 inet_ntoa(newAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddr.sin_port));
                break;
        }
    }

 }



}
return 0;
}
```

client :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 4444

int main(){

int clientSocket, ret;
struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
char buffer[1024];
    char Temp[4];

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(clientSocket < 0){
    printf("[-]Error in connection.\n");
    exit(1);
}
printf("[+]Client Socket is created.\n");

memset(&serverAddr, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr));
serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

ret = connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, 
sizeof(serverAddr));
if(ret < 0){
    printf("[-]Error in connection.\n");
    exit(1);
}
printf("[+]Connected to Server.\n");
   bzero(buffer,512);

   int words = 0;
    char c;

while(1){


             recv(clientSocket, Temp, 1024, 0);
    if(recv(clientSocket, Temp, 1024, 0) < 0){
        printf("[-]Error in receiving data.\n");
    }
           printf("Temp : %s \n",Temp);
       if(strcmp(Temp, ":exit") == 0){
        close(clientSocket);
        printf("[-]Disconnected from server.\n");

    } exit(1);
}



return 0;
}
```

Please, can anyone tell me how can I solve this problem, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several problems with your client code:

```
char Temp[4];
...
recv(clientSocket, Temp, 1024, 0);
```

Here you are reading up to 1024 bytes into `Temp` although only 4 bytes are allocated for `Temp`. If you read more than 4 bytes thus other data structures will be filled with the read data, i.e. a classic buffer overflow.

```
printf("Temp : %s \n",Temp);
```

Here you are assuming that Temp is a `\0` terminated string, which it is not. Therefore it will print out data starting with the position of `&Temp` up to a `\0` byte it will find somewhere (way outside of `Temp` based on your output).

```
if(strcmp(Temp, ":exit") == 0){
```

Even though `Temp` is only 4 bytes this statement assumes at least 6 bytes (5 byte string and `\0` for end of string marker).

Similar problems are also at the server code. Also strange is that your `buffer` variable is initialized but otherwise never used. My guess is that you originally wanted to use this instead of `Temp` for sending and receiving.

Comment: yes you're right...i uploaded the code many times and i didn't see those errors, thank you so much !

Comment: @mery: I have no idea how your current code looks like but did you address the other things I've mentioned in my answer, in both client and server?

Comment: yes, you helped me solving the problem thank you again